Expected vs empirical loss with data augmentation
In a typical supervised learning setup, we assume our data $X$ with labels $Y$ comes from a data distribution $(X,Y) \sim P(X,Y)$.
The expected loss for some loss function, $L$, is:
$R_{L,P,f} = \mathbb{E}[L(y, f(x))]$
Similarly, the empirical risk is:
$R_{n,L,P,f} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} L(y_i, f(x_i))$
It is common to use data augmentation methods in fields like computer vision, where the sampled data points $X_i$ are used to generate other data points with the same label, essentially increasing the dataset size for "free".
How does this data augmentation affect our sample approximation of the expected loss, are there any formal proofs/theory that the augmented empirical risk is still a good estimator of the true loss. I would assume it changes the distribution we are sampling from by adding more mass around the already sampled points in our dataset.
Additionally, does something like this work for reinforcement learning as well, where the objective $\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim{\pi}}[R(\tau)]$ is approximated with sample trajectories from the policy. Is it valid to augment trajectories as well, or are there certain assumptions/restrictions on the augmentation function to still have good statistical properties.
